# Chef - creating a cronjob and testing it with Inspec

Tags: cron, chef-infra, inspec

I'm trying to set up a cronjob to run a command (in this example `ls`) once every day. For this I am using the [cron resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html).

The problem is that I don't know how to test it with Inspect. I tried using [crontab](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/crontab/) but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
// code
cron 'my-ls' do
  minute '1'
  hour '0'
  command 'ls'
end

// test
describe crontab.commands('ls') do
  its('minutes') { should cmp '1' }
  its('hours') { should cmp '0' }
end
```

It's failing saying that:

```
×  hours should cmp == "0"

     expected: "0"
          got: []

     (compared using `cmp` matcher)

     ×  minutes should cmp == "1"

     expected: "1"
          got: []

     (compared using `cmp` matcher)
```

PS: I also tried with `cron_d` using the [cron cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/cron#readme)

Comment: Have you tried adding the user to the describe line? e.g. `crontab('root').commands('ls')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest way I could get these tests working:

Step 1:  Create a text file named `cronls.txt` with this data:

```
1 0 * * * ls -al
```

Step 2:  Turn it into a cron job with this command:

```
crontab -a cronls.txt
```

Step 3:  In your Chef cookbook, add these controls to your `default_test.rb`:

```
control 'cron-1' do
  describe crontab do
    its('commands') { should include 'ls -al' }
  end
end

control 'cron-2' do
  describe crontab.commands('ls -al') do
    its('minutes') { should cmp '1' }
    its('hours') { should cmp '0' }
  end
end
```

Step 4:  Execute your InSpec tests:

```
inspec exec test/integration/default/default_test.rb
```

The results are what you would expect:

```
  ✔  cron-1: crontab for current user
     ✔  crontab for current user commands should include "ls -al"
  ✔  cron-2: crontab for current user with command == "ls -al"
     ✔  crontab for current user with command == "ls -al" minutes should cmp == "1"
     ✔  crontab for current user with command == "ls -al" hours should cmp == "0"
```

This isn't the only way to do this (or even the best way), but it should get you going.  For more options on the `crontab` resource, read the InSpec documentation:

https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html